# Can't connect to MySQL database via hostinger.com

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, hosting

I am trying to connect to mysql database through phpmyadmin on my **hostinger.com** account, but everytime i signup to my form that created, the data that i entered doesnt go to my database (ive done it on my xampp server, so im sure i didnt do anything wrong) also i have changed the database username, name, host and password from:

```
<?php

$dbServername = "localhost";
$dbUsername = "root";
$dbPassword = "";
$dbName = "loginsystem";

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbServername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);
?>
```

to

```
<?php

$dbServername = "serverexample.hostinger.com";
$dbUsername = "u123456789_username";
$dbPassword = "password";
$dbName = "u123456789_name";

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbServername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);
?>
```

and still it didnt work, i also tried searching for a database connection tester which is this:

```
<?php
# Fill our vars and run on cli
# $ php -f db-connect-test.php

$dbname = 'u123456789_name';
$dbuser = 'u123456789_username';
$dbpass = 'password';
$dbhost = 'serverexample.hostinger.com';

$connect = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("Unable to Connect to '$dbhost'");
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die("Could not open the db '$dbname'");

$test_query = "SHOW TABLES FROM $dbname";
$result = mysql_query($test_query);

$tblCnt = 0;
while($tbl = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $tblCnt++;
  #echo $tbl[0]."<br />\n";
}

if (!$tblCnt) {
  echo "There are no tables<br />\n";
} else {
  echo "There are $tblCnt tables<br />\n";
}
```

and it shows me this: http://u920040733.hostingerapp.com/

EDIT: The problem was the server name, it should be localhost XD.

Comment: Please add a screenshot of what it shows you rather than send people away from here. Also, that link doesn't work, but guessing that's your issue?

Comment: Can you check your error log for more information?

Comment: Is it PHPMyAdmin that can't connect to the database or is it your application? If it is your application, add some error handling: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php to get the actual error message. You should also check your servers error log.

Comment: @Dammeul yes thats my issue now, i think its supposed to show my database tables based on the code i got from that database connection tester. also i checked my logs and i cant find any error logs

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i think its the application

Comment: im not sure but i think my main problem right now is about the database username, name, host and password. but im not sure if its all that

Comment: Definitely need to do some debugging and get some error logging

Comment: actually the website is just new and i just tried if the login system i made will work online, because i only tried it offline through xampp

Comment: _"i think its the application"_ - Is the connection in your application or does it fail when you're trying to log in to PHPMyAdmin? PHPMyAdmin is just a web based management tool for MySQL databases. If you're building an application, it doesn't interact/have anything to do with PHPMyAdmin. You're then connecting directly to the MySQL server. Anyway, we need to see the real error message. Without it, we're basically just sitting here guessing.

Comment: `u920040733.hostingerapp.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500`
thats the error showing to me

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you database is not accessible from outside your domain

[Hostinger Tutorial](https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/how-to-connect-php-to-mysql)

Cheers,

Comment: **Unable to Connect to 'server173.hostinger.com'**